# Combine scan with network request to update model in RxSwift

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-swift

Currently I'm having a `Observable` created using `scan` to update underlying model using a `PublishSubject` like this:

```swift
class ViewModel {

    private enum Action {
        case updateName(String)
    }

    private let product: Observable<Product>
    private let actions = PublishSubject<Action>()

    init(initialProduct: Product) {
        product = actions
            .scan(initialProduct, accumulator: { (oldProduct, action) -> Product in
                var newProduct = oldProduct

                switch action {
                case .updateName(let name):
                    newProduct.name = name
                }

                return newProduct
            })
            .startWith(initialProduct)
            .share()
    }

    func updateProductName(_ name: String) {
        actions.onNext(.updateName(name))
    }

    private func getProductDetail() {
        /// This will call a network request
    }
}
```

Every "local" actions like update product's name, prices... is done by using method like `updateProductName(_ name: String)` above. But what if I want to have a network request that also update the product, and can be called every time I want, for example after a button tap, or after calling `updateProductName`?

// UPDATE: After read iWheelBuy's comment and Daniel's answer, I ended up using 2 more actions

```swift
class ViewModel {

    private enum Action {
        case getDetail
        case updateProduct(Product)
    }

    ///....

    init(initialProduct: Product) {
        product = actions
            .scan(initialProduct, accumulator: { (oldProduct, action) -> Product in
                var newProduct = oldProduct

                switch action {
                case .updateName(let name):
                    newProduct.name = name

                case .getDetail:
                    self.getProductDetail()

                case .updateProduct(let p):
                    return p
                }

                return newProduct
            })
            .startWith(initialProduct)
            .share()
    }

    func getProductDetail() {
        actions.onNext(.getDetail)
    }

    private func getProductDetail(id: Int) {
        ProductService.getProductDetail(id) { product in
            self.actions.onNext(.updateProduct(product))
        }
    }
}
```

But I feel that, I trigger side effect (call network request) inside `scan`, without updating the model, is that something wrong?

Also how can I use a "rx" network request?

```swift
    // What if I want to use this method instead of the one above,
    // without subscribe inside viewmodel?
    private func rxGetProductDetail(id: Int) -> Observable<Product> {
        return ProductService.rxGetProductDetail(id: Int)
    }
```

Comment: why don't you create an extra Action case? (`case fromNetwork(Product)`)  Then map your network response to Action and bind to actions publish subject

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why @iWheelBuy didn't make a real answer because their comment is the correct answer. Given the hybrid approach to Rx in your question, I expect something like the below will accommodate your style:

```
class ViewModel {

    private enum Action {
        case updateName(String)
        case updateProduct(Product)
    }

    private let product: Observable<Product>
    private let actions = PublishSubject<Action>()
    private var disposable: Disposable?

    init(initialProduct: Product) {
        product = actions
            .scan(initialProduct, accumulator: { (oldProduct, action) -> Product in
                var newProduct = oldProduct

                switch action {
                case .updateName(let name):
                    newProduct.name = name
                case .updateProduct(let product):
                    newProduct = product
                }

                return newProduct
            })
            .startWith(initialProduct)
            .share()

            // without a subscribe, none of this matters. I assume you just didn't show all your code.
    }

    deinit {
        disposable?.dispose()
    }

    func updateProductName(_ name: String) {
        actions.onNext(.updateName(name))
    }

    private func getProductDetail() {
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://foo.com")!)
        disposable?.dispose()
        disposable = URLSession.shared.rx.data(request: request)
            .map { try JSONDecoder().decode(Product.self, from: $0) }
            .map { Action.updateProduct($0) }
            .subscribe(
                onNext: { [actions] in actions.onNext($0) },
                onError: { error in /* handle error */ }
        )
    }
}
```

The style above is still pretty imperative but if you don't want your use of Rx to leak out of the view model it's okay.

If you want to see a "full Rx" setup, you might find my sample repo interesting: https://github.com/danielt1263/RxEarthquake

### UPDATE

> But I feel that, I trigger side effect (call network request) inside scan, without updating the model, is that something wrong?

The `scan` function should be pure with no side effects. Calling a network request inside it's closure is inappropriate.

Comment: thanks for answering, please read my updated question for more information

Comment: Because I'm lazy (:

Comment: @kientux I have updated my answer to include your new question. If you have any other questions, it would probably be a good idea to make a new question rather than piling onto this question.